# Global Address Book DistinguishedFolderId

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I need to retrieve contacts from Exchange server global address book using this SOAP request

[FindItem Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa566107%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx)

How can I get DistinguishedFolderId for Exchange global address book?

Comment: This can live here, it's an EWS API question, that particular topic has better coverage here than on SF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global Address Book has't DistinguishedFolderId because it is a AD not Exchange object.